# Un pas vers la nouvelle orthographe… ou pas ? — One step towards new orthography... or not?

Tags: discussion, language

Par exemple, *trente et un* devient *trente-et-un*, *paraître* devient *paraitre*, *réglementaire* devient *règlementaire*, *revolver* devient *révolver*, *des après-midi* devient *des après-midis*, *porte-monnaie* devient *portemonnaie*, etc. Je vous laisse zyeuter par [ici](http://www.orthographe-recommandee.info/.), et ça vaut aussi le coup de parcourir [la liste des mots modifiés par la réforme de 1990](http://www.renouvo.org/liste.php?t=3&lettre=a) pour avoir une idée de l'étendue.

Par curiosité, est-ce qu'il y a des gens qui pensent qu'il serait temps de se mettre à la nouvelle orthographe ?
Personnellement je ne suis pas contre, je remarque seulement que j'emploie assez souvent l'ancienne parce la nouvelle fait en général un peu mal aux yeux. Mais avec un peu d'efforts, je me dis que ça peut finir par passer.

Votre avis ?

La réponse aura certainement une influence sur mes choix, tout du moins dans les cas où je me pose la question. Éventuellement j'essayerai de me la poser plus souvent.

---

For example, *trente et un* becomes *trente-et-un*, *paraître* becomes *paraitre*, *réglementaire* becomes *règlementaire*, *revolver* becomes *révolver*, *des après-midi* becomes *des après-midis*, *porte-monnaie* becomes *portemonnaie*, etc. I will let you peruse [here](http://www.orthographe-recommandee.info/.), and it's worth it to take a look at [the list of words modified by the 1990 reform](http://www.renouvo.org/liste.php?t=3&lettre=a) to have an idea of its extent.

Out of curiosity, is there anyone who thinks it's time to use the new orthography?
Personally, I'm not against, I simply notice that I often use the old spelling because in general the new one is a bit of an eyesore. But with a little effort, it might pass.

What do you think?

The answer will certainly have an influence on my choices, or at least when I ask myself the question. I might try to wonder about it more often.

Comment: Le mec qui me fera écrire *ognon* pourra se payer un coup de champagne.

Comment: Plutôt « ou pas », pour moi.

Comment: @Evpok: avec du *poignon* ou avec du *pognon* ? ;-)

Comment: Comme il veut, [chui](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/839/82) pas sectaire.

Comment: @Evpok: By the way, je crois que d'une certaine façon j'ai réussi. Je ne suis pas sûr que ça mérite l'ouverture d'une bouteille pour autant :-)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Of course it does !

Answer (score 4):

Je crois que la majorité des personnes ne sont pas à l'aise avec la nouvelle orthographe. Comme l'Académie française n'oblige pas l'adoption de la réforme, je ne crois pas que nous devrions sur ce site, puisque l'orthographe traditionnelle est toujours correcte.

Bien sûr, les personnes qui désirent rédiger leurs questions, réponses et commentaires avec la nouvelle orthographe sont les bienvenues à le faire.

---

I think that the majority of people are not comfortable with the new orthography. As the Académie française does not push for the adoption of the reform, I don't think we should either on this site, as the traditional orthography is still correct.

Of course, those who want to write their questions, answers and comments with the new orthography are welcome to do so.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais évoqué une quelconque obligation, loin de là. Je voulais simplement tâter les états d'âme, et le moins qu'on puisse dire c'est que peu parmi celles qu'on trouve ici semblent attirées par le changement :-)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Qu'avais-tu en tête alors, si la réponse avait été négative? Rien ne t'empêche d'utiliser la nouvelle orthographe si le cœur t'en dit, même si les autres ne veulent pas le faire.